# How many DML statements will be execute for below code?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, dmlexception

Below is the logic/Method i have built to eliminate error while inserting case Object. Consider a example when i try insert case object inside try block, if it is throwing an error while inserting, I will find the field name from exception message make that field as **null** , Continue insert with other field to avoid the data loss(has it was one of my requirement). Even i put loop counter to avoid infinite loop.

**Basically my question How many DML statements will be execute? for below scenario ?** 
Consider there are five field with error, Statement **upsert caseObjToUpsert;** 
fail to insert for 5 times & code  will remove those field value by replacing NULL and 6th attempt insertion will be successful.

**How many DML statements is executed? 5 error + 1 Success = 6 DML ? 
or 1 Success = 1 DML ?**

```
 private void errorHandling(case caseObjToUpsert){
        Boolean errorInUpsert;
        Integer loopCounter=0;
        do{
            errorInUpsert=false;
            loopCounter++;
            try{
                upsert caseObjToUpsert; 
            }catch(Exception ex){
                errorInUpsert=true;
                String searchPattern='\\[(.*?)\\]';
                Matcher MatcherValues=pattern.compile(searchPattern).matcher(ex.getMessage());
                if (MatcherValues.find()){
                    caseObjToUpsert.put(MatcherValues.group(1),null);
                }
            }
        }while(errorInUpsert && loopCounter <10);

        if(loopCounter==10){
            throw (new applicationException('applicationException'));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Santanu says, it would be six DML statements; a failed DML is *still* a DML. However, your main problem is that you're not checking for all field errors at once.

Here's a better design:

```
Database.upsertResult sr;
Integer retryCounter = 0;
do {
  sr = Database.upsert(caseObjToUpsert, false);
  for(Database.Error dmlError: sr.getErrors()) {
    for(String field: dmlError.getFields()) {
      caseObjToUpsert.put(field, null);
    }
  }
} while(retryCounter++ < RETRY_LIMIT && !sr.isSuccess());
if(!sr.isSuccess()) {
  throw new ApplicationException('Application Exception.');
}
```

Instead of stopping on the first error, we actually try to process *as many errors as possible* all at once. This means if five fields have errors, there should still only be two DML (1 error and 1 success). There's still different types of errors that could occur, like record-level errors, so you might want to think about handling those separately.

I feel like 10 retries is likely too many; if you get past 3 or 4, it's unlikely you're going to save. I would probably set RETRY_LIMIT to 5 as a maximum, and probably check StatusCode against a list of known possible errors that you can resolve. For example, if the error is `StatusCode.REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING`, setting the value to null won't help you, so you could abort early in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Error in DML during insert is part of your DML count.

```
5 error + 1 Success = 6 DML
```

Since you are processing each record for DML, it will be best to buliky it.

I would suggest to use `Database.upsert(records, false)` and then process those failed records and finally insert those corrected records in a single goal.